# problem while designing xml layout

Tags: android

I am creating a layout,I have total 10 textviews placed vertically.On th e left side of   4th text i have to place image.Can anybody help

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: How can someone help when there is no code

Comment: Saurabh i have uploaded my xml on url http://www.megaupload.com/?d=LVBBO4PU

Comment: upload the xml on gist/pastie/pastebin so that we can see/edit it right away. Although what you're asking doesn't seem to be very tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourIamge"` in your forth `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout/@orientation="vertical"` for your layout and put the image and the 4th `TextView` in an other `LinearLayout/@orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: No sorry, I don't want to use megaupload for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation as the 4th element and put an `ImageView` and `TextView` within it:

```
  ....
  <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
          <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
          <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
      </LinearLayout>
  <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    ....
```